# Java best practice: More detailed class variable in subclass

Tags: java, graph, drawable

i'm modelling a drawable planar graph in java for some algorithms. 
My basic classes are:

```
public class Node {
    private String label;
}
```

and

```
public class Edge {
    private Node node0;
    private Node node1;
}
```

This works pretty good for the algorithms. For drawing the graph, i extended the node-class with positions:

```
public class GraphicalNode extends Node {
    private int x;
    private int y;
}
```

My problem is the class for drawable edges. I'd like to write something like this:

```
public class GraphicalEdge extends Edge {
    private GraphicalNode node0;
    private GraphicalNode node1;
}
```

But i've never seen a design like this before. And on top of that, the compiler need a constructor `public GraphicalNode(Node node0, Node node1)` for the superclass.

Does anyone have an idea to realize that?

Comment: eh? I can't really follow what you're saying, here.

Comment: Since your `GraphicalNode` **is** a `Node`, you can store it in the members of `Edge` and add two getters to `GraphicalEdge` which encapsulate the casting when accessing `GraphicalNode`

Comment: @AndreasFester But then i would risk a ClassCastException in case of storing a real Node in GraphicalEdge and not a GraphicalNode, wouldn't i?

Comment: Yes, that is the drawback - you need to make sure to store the proper objects. You could use the generics based approach by @wero - there the compiler assures that you only store `GraphicalNodes` into `GraphicalEdges`. In any case: avoid the member duplication in the sub class.

Comment: Thank you. I think weros approach is the smartest one in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Maybe I misunderstood something here - the downvotes will show - but...</sub>

This sounds like a textbook example for using [Covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

When you have a class `Edge` that has a method `Node getNode()`, then you can define a more specific return type for this method, in a class that `extends Edge`. For example:

```
class Node {}
class Edge {
    Node getNode();
}

class GraphicalNode extends Node {}
class GraphicalEdge extends Edge {
    // This really overrides the method, with a more specific return type!
    @Override
    GraphicalNode getNode();
}
```

Or, using the classes that you provided, extended with the constructors that you mentioned, and some getters, assembled into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
public class WhatIsCovariance
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Node n0 = new Node();
        Node n1 = new Node();
        Edge e0 = new Edge(n0, n1);

        Node n = e0.getNode0(); // Works


        GraphicalNode gn0 = new GraphicalNode();
        GraphicalNode gn1 = new GraphicalNode();
        GraphicalEdge ge0 = new GraphicalEdge(gn0, gn1);

        GraphicalNode gn = ge0.getNode0(); // Works
    }
}

class Node
{
    private String label;
}

class Edge
{
    private Node node0;
    private Node node1;

    Edge(Node node0, Node node1)
    {
        this.node0 = node0;
        this.node1 = node1;
    }

    public Node getNode0()
    {
        return node0;
    }

    public Node getNode1()
    {
        return node1;
    }
}

class GraphicalNode extends Node
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
}

class GraphicalEdge extends Edge
{
    private GraphicalNode node0;
    private GraphicalNode node1;

    GraphicalEdge(GraphicalNode node0, GraphicalNode node1)
    {
        super(node0, node1);

        this.node0 = node0;
        this.node1 = node1;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphicalNode getNode0()
    {
        return node0;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphicalNode getNode1()
    {
        return node1;
    }

}
```

---

The key point here is: When you have a reference of the type `Edge`, then you can only obtain a `Node` from it (even if the object that the reference refers to actually **is** a `GraphicalEdge`). Only when the type of the reference is a `GraphicalEdge`, you can also obtain a `GraphicalNode` from it.

This is handy in many contexts, and often allows a clean separation of concerns: When a method only has to operate on `Edge` and `Node` objects, and is not interested in their *graphical* representation, then you can write its signature using the base classes:

```
void computeSomething(Edge edge) {
    Node n0 = edge.getNode();
    Node n1 = edge.getNode();
    ...
}

void run() {
    GraphicialEdge e = new GraphicalEdge(...);

    computeSomething(e);
}
```

When a method really *needs* the graphical representation, you let it take the graphical edge:

```
void drawSomething(GraphicalEdge edge) {
    GraphicalNode n0 = edge.getNode();
    GraphicalNode n1 = edge.getNode();
    ...
}

void run() {
    GraphicialEdge e = new GraphicalEdge(...);

    computeSomething(e); // Works
    drawSomething(e); // Works as well

    Edge edge = e;
    drawSomething(edge); // Does not work. A GraphicalEdge is required.
}
```

---

A side note, or maybe the key point, considering that your question was particularly about...

### the class variables:

With the current design that you sketched there, each `GraphicalEdge` will store its nodes **twice** - once as a `GraphicalNode`, and once as a simple `Node`. This could be avoided, for example, by defining things as interfaces:

```
interface Node {}
interface Edge { 
    Node getNode();
}

interface GraphicalNode extends Node {}
interface GraphicalEdge extends Edge { 
    @Override
    GraphicalNode getNode();
}

class DefaultEdge implements GraphicalEdge { ... }
```

---

Using generics, as [wero suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34875111/3182664), may add some more degrees of freedom, and maybe an even cleaner and more flexible design, in view of further `Node` types. For example, you might later want to introduce something like a `ColoredGraphicalNode`, and this could nicely be covered by the generic type parameter. But it comes at the cost of somewhat more cryptic method signatures: Writing the methods in the generic form, that allows "routing through" the required type information can become a bit cumbersome, depending on how far you want to go there.

Comment: I got the partly the same answer in another board, i asked the question :D
I didn't get the approach with the covariance. This one is my absolutely favourite! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use generics and parameterize Edge with the Node class

```
public class Edge<N extends Node> {
    private N node0;
    private N node1;
    public Edge(N n0, N n1) { this.node0 = n0; this.node1 = n1; }
}
```

GraphicalEdge then becomes

```
public class GraphicalEdge extends Edge<GraphicalNode> {
    public GraphicalEdge (GraphicalNode n0, GraphicalNode n1) { super(n0, n1); }
}
```

Note: These types of class hierarchies often become difficult to handle.
You could also simply decide to put the `x` and `y` members into to Node base class, no need for hierarchies.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. This looks interesting. I think about this solution.

I don't want to put x and y to Node, because i won't need them, if i use only the model of a graph and not the view of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do so is to have your `Node` class implement `Point`:

```
public interface Point {
    double getX();
    double getY();
}
```

like this:

```
public class Node implements Point {
    private String label;
    // ...
}
```

then you can have an `Edge` class like your original one:

```
public class Edge {
    private Node node0;
    private Node node1;

    public List<Node> getNodes() {
    // ...
}
```

and an object responsible for drawing:

```
public class PointsDrawer {

    public void drawPoints(List<? extends PointPoint> pointsToDraw) {
        // draw logic here
    }
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
Edge edge = new Edge();
// initialization here ...
PointsDrawer pd = new PointsDrawer();
pd.drawPoints(edge.getNodes());
```

using this you decople the drawing logic from your data structures and you only have to hold the *x* and *y* coordinates in your `Node` class. You can decouple it further by storing the `Point` data attached using a decorator or a `Map`.

Comment: Thank you. But this is the same problem like storing the x- and y-coordinates in Node. If i want to use only the model of a graph, the coordinates are to much information.
The map is actual a possible solution as well. I just want to use as few datastructures as possible. As a class variable, i won't need the map.

Comment: You can put the coordinates in a `Map` like this: `Map<Node, Point>`